# Tomcat cluster for SSL tracking mode

Tags: session, tomcat, ssl, cluster-computing, tomcat8

I want to remove node affinity in a Tomcat8 cluster set on docker containers.
For security concerns, we had to bind the tomcat's session to the SSL sessions using `<tracking-mode>` set to SSL.
While using the `SimpleTcpCluster` configuration, we see that the SSL session Ids are replicated along the cluster nodes of the setup but the session doesn't remain valid across nodes.

When we were using COOKIES to hold the JSESSIONID, the cluster nodes used to work well even with a non-sticky load balancing algorithm but after moving to SSL, the session is not getting resumed if a new node starts processing requests.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!